# How do I detect in Watchkit when iPhone disconnects

Tags: watchkit, wcsession

I have a simple app that mirrors some information on a watch that also plays audio based on the information, I know how to detect when the watch disconnects from the phone using:

```
if (WCSession.default.isReachable) { do something }
```

but I cannot find how to do the same thing on the watch. The same line of code compiles in WatchKit but doesn't actually do anything. Any suggestions please?